# Responsive CSS triangles jQuery not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

So, as funny as this is, I just recently found the concept of CSS triangles using element borders.  I'm trying to implement this in one of my custom Wordpress themes, and I'm running into an issue.  I'm trying to add a triangle to the bottom of a div (kind of like a banner), but that div contains text that can be set by the user, so I can't hard code the width of the box and the triangle.  This led me to jQuery to try to get the box width, and resize the triangle appropriately.  When I first tried a simple script to set both borders to half the total parent width, it seems I ran into an issue with the box resizing itself as elements load (seems like slow font loading).  I simply wrapped the script to fire on element resize, however it doesn't seem to be triggering.  This is causing my triangle to stay larger than the box it's under.  You can see the effect here:

http://dev3.thoughtspacedesigns.com

Here's my code:

HTML

```
<div id="logo-box">
    <h1><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></h1>
    <div id="logo-box-point"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#logo-box{
    background:#374140;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:20px;
    position:relative;
}

#logo-box h1{
    color:#f2f2f2;
}

#logo-box-point{
    content: ' ';
    width:0px;
    height:0px;
    border-left: 0px solid transparent;
    border-right: 0px solid transparent;
    border-top:25px solid #374140;
    border-bottom:0;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-25px;
    left:0px;
    z-index:2;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(function(){
    function triangleSize(){
            var logoBoxWidth = $("#logo-box").width();
            $("#logo-box-point").css({"border-left-width":logoBoxWidth/2, "border-right-width":logoBoxWidth/2});
    }
    triangleSize();
    $("#logo-box").resize(function(){
            triangleSize();
    }
    );
}
);
```

I also tried this using the .change() function, with no effect.  Any ideas on what's causing this content jump, or why my function isn't firing?  I have a suspicion it has to do with the display inline block piece, but I'm at a loss on how to fix it as display:inline-block is the only way the div would display correctly.

Comment: Please don't link to live code. As soon as that page changes, your question becomes useless.

Comment: This question will be useless when answered anyway.  This is a specific example that won't apply to other situations.

Comment: Then please delete it. It is explicitly off topic here. The entire purpose of Stack Overflow is to provided canonical answers to common problems, not to help individuals debug one-off scenarios.

Comment: This question will always remain relevant for those interested in responsive CSS triangles, but this specific application pertains to a small bug that's probably a small CSS / code mess up somewhere.  This will be a valuable resource for those looking for ways to make responsive CSS triangles.  I'm not looking for an argument, simply a second set of eyes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resize wont fire on an element like that, use:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
        triangleSize();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TDcuD/

note: Your code didn't seem to account for the padding of the DIV either, which I've done in the fiddle.

Comment: Decided to go another route.  Thanks though.  This actually isn't quite what I was looking for but never the less it's a good answer to the question.  Marking it as solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using plain css also

```
 div
    {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 30px 338px 0 338px;
    border-color: #007bff transparent transparent transparent;
    line-height: 0px;
    _border-color: #007bff #000000 #000000 #000000;
    _filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Chroma(color='#000000');
    }
```

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/prTrv/1/)

Comment: I get that much, but my triangles are responsive, not static width.

Comment: have a look at this plugin.. http://olalindberg.com/2009/07/06/drawing_with_juery/

Comment: That's pretty cool, and I may look into using it, but it seems like a bit much for an implementation of just one triangle.  I'm interested in seeing where the issue lies in my code.  Thanks for the resource though!

Comment: If logowidth is 602px ..the formula will be right ..Is it responsive based on screen sizes ..

Comment: The text in #logo-box can change dpenedent on the site title.  It won't always be the same width.